# ubuntu 20.04 - printer is gone

Tags: printing

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. The printer (connected to my router) was recognised right away and all alone. Really nice.
When I am restarting the system I see sometimes a notification popping up that my printer was found. That's nice, but now I'd need my printer and it seems to be gone.

What can I do that the printer remains installed and available?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue.
I have downloaded the drivers from Samsung https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2070-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16450377

install it.

```
cd /path/to/download/directory
tar -xvzf uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz
cd uld_V1.00.39_01.17/uld
sudo sh install.sh
```

It is not all.

1. Important!! Go to Additional Printer Setting.

   2. then Add  >Select Samsung M2070 >Forward
   3. Select Samsung > Forward > Select model ml3050.
   4. Print test page.

Hope it will work well.